# Simulating location for apple watch simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to maintain watch app for watch os 2. I need to simulate location on simulator for watch and I can't change location. (can't press ok) I have already change location on iphone simulator and location is okay on phone simulator. How shall I do so that I can change location on apple watch simulator?

[image]

[image]